# Where Do I put the MuiThemeProvider Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I'm currently developing a new React application using Material Ui for my choice of a css library. I'm trying to get it to play nice with react-router. I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put MuiThemeProvider. The docs example wraps the main app component around it.

This works fine without any additional components from react-router. But when I want to render the rest of the child components from react router it throws an error.

Index.js

```
  import React from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
  import injectTapEventPlugin from "react-tap-event-plugin";
  import routes from "./routes";
  import { Router, browserHistory} from "react-router";
  import "../public/css/index.css";
  import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";

  injectTapEventPlugin();

  ReactDOM.render(
       <MuiThemeProvider>
          <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
      </MuiThemeProvider>,
       document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

and App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavigationBar from "./NavigationBar";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationBar />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
     );
  }
}   

export default App;
```

The error being thrown is this

> warning.js:36Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected
>   a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `WelcomePage`.

and

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `WelcomePage`.
>       at invariant (invariant.js:44)
>       at instantiateReactComponent (instantiateReactComponent.js:77)
>       at instantiateChild (ReactChildReconciler.js:44)
>       at ReactChildReconciler.js:71
>       at traverseAllChildrenImpl (traverseAllChildren.js:77)
>       at traverseAllChildren (traverseAllChildren.js:172)
>       at Object.instantiateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:70)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerInstantiateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:187)
>       at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:226)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (ReactDOMComponent.js:697)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually wrap my main container's content with the MuiThemeProvider component.

For example in my router I have (notice AppContainer as base component):

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={AppContainer}>
        <IndexRoute
            getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
                System.import('./containers/home/home')
                    .then(loadRoute(cb))
                    .catch(errorLoading);
            }}
        />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

And in this AppContainer I have:

```
class AppContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                <div className="content">
                    <h1>Here is my app</h1>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that but i get this error Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `MuiThemeProvider`, expected a single ReactElement.
    in MuiThemeProvider (at AppContainer.js:8)
    in AppContainer (created by RouterContext)
    in RouterContext (created by Router)
    in Router (at index.js:11)

Comment: You're right you need to have a single element inside of MuiThemeProvider. Just updated my answer